# Bind function to window resize and window scroll but also invoke it immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

So, on a web-page there are some components that have to be re-positioned whenever the browser window is re-sized or scrolled.

```
$( window ).on( 'resize scroll', reposition );
```

where `reposition` is the function that does that.

However, that function has to be invoked immediately too. (By immediately, I mean on page initialization - inside DOM-ready.) This needs to be done to set up the initial positions of the components.

I'm currently doing it like so:

```
$( window ).on( 'resize scroll', reposition );
reposition();
```

I noticed that this also works:

```
$( window ).on( 'resize scroll load', reposition );
```

I believe this is reliable - the `load` is never fired before the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

But this delays the execution until after all page resources have been loaded (which could take a few seconds depending on how many images there are on the page). Is there any way to tell jQuery that the bound function should be invoked immediately too?

Like:

```
$( window ).on( 'resize scroll now', reposition );
```

or

```
$( window ).on( 'resize scroll ()', reposition );
```

These examples are of course invalid, but I was wondering if jQuery's `on` method has such functionality. I guess, I could manually implement this functionality into `on`, but I'd like to first check if it has that already...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', reposition).trigger('scroll');
```

To set and trigger an event callback.

Although you should be setting this in the $(document).ready just to be safe. Basically your code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize scroll', reposition).trigger('scroll');
});
```

So you're guaranteed that the DOM will be ready for you to mess around with

Comment: I'm sure you realize it can also be `.trigger('resize')` or `.resize()` or `scroll()`

Comment: Ah of course. I will have this `$( window ).triggerHandler( 'resize' );` at the end of my ready-handler (since I'm adding multiple functions and I want them all to be invoked immediately).

Comment: @imeVidas: type this into your console (function(user) { var $voteUp = $('.user-details:contains(' + user + ')').parents('.answer').find('[class^=vote-up]'); window.scrollTo(0, $voteUp.offset().top - 50); (function blink() { $voteUp.fadeOut('fast', function() { $(this).fadeIn('fast', blink) }) })() })('qwertymk')

Comment: @qwertymk: and don't forget the **✔**

Comment: @imeVidas: feel free to reuse.